# solving non-linear set of equations using NSolve in order to get all roots

Tags: equation-solving

```
vpw = 3.3
Mp = 80
rp = 0.014*Mp
b0 = 26.31016273 - (1.7168*10^3/t) - 3.5519*Log[t]
b1 = 24.65681838 - (1.547*10^3/t) - 3.4314*Log[t]
b2 = 9.080370819 - (6.9445*10^2/t) - 1.2222*Log[t]
g = b0 + b1*phip + b2*phip^2
dg = b1 + 2*b2*phip
ddg = 2*b2
dddg = 0

S1 = (1/(phip*rp*vpw)) + (1/(1 - phip)) - (2*g - 2*(1 - 2*phip)*dg - phip*(1 - phip)*ddg)
S2 = -(1/(phip^2*rp*vpw)) + (1/(1 - phip)^2) - (6*dg - 3*(1 - 2*phip)*ddg - 
      phip*(1 - phip)*dddg)
```

I have tried `FindRoot` to solve `S1==0` and `S2==0` but it gives only one root which may be real or imaginary depending upon initial guess.

In order to get all real roots, I am trying to solve `S1==0` and `S2==0` by using `NSolve`. But it takes too long time and does not give any solution.

In order to get all possible real roots of above non-linear equations, please suggest me the possible solution of my problem.
Thanks in advance and Regards

Comment: Just to clarify: You want to solve for `t` and `phip`?

Comment: Here goes a numerical solution for you `{phip -> -1.2873402582429818, t -> 414.62463948474345}`. As far as I can see there is no real root for `t<0`. Also using `Plot3D` I doubt if there is any solution to `{S1==0, S2==0}` for `t>0` and `phip>1`. Function is also unbounded in that region.

Answer (score 1):

```
vpw = 3.3; 
Mp = 80; 
rp = 0.014*Mp; 
b0 = 26.31016273 - 1.7168*(10^3/t) - 3.5519*Log[t]; 
b1 = 24.65681838 - 1.547*(10^3/t) - 3.4314*Log[t]; 
b2 = 9.080370819 - 6.9445*(10^2/t) - 1.2222*Log[t]; 
g = b0 + b1*phip + b2*phip^2; 
dg = b1 + 2*b2*phip; 
ddg = 2*b2; 
dddg = 0; 

S1 = 1/(phip*rp*vpw) + 1/(1 - phip) - (2*g - 2*(1 - 2*phip)*dg - 
     phip*(1 - phip)*ddg); 
S2 = -(1/(phip^2*rp*vpw)) + 1/(1 - phip)^2 - 
    (6*dg - 3*(1 - 2*phip)*ddg - phip*(1 - phip)*dddg); 

   p = Apply[{phip, t} /. FindRoot[{S1 == 0, S2 == 0}, {phip, #1}, {t, #2}] & , 
   {{-2, 400}, {-0.05, 20}, {3, 800}}, {1}]
```

{{-1.28734, 414.625}, {-0.0436006, 23.3922}, {2.6102, 820.852}}

```
ContourPlot[{S1 == 0, S2 == 0}, {phip, -2, 3}, {t, 0, 1000}, 
  PlotTheme -> "Detailed", PlotPoints -> 100, 
  Epilog -> {Red, PointSize[Large], Point[p]}]
```

[image: Contourplot3]

```
   ContourPlot[{S1 == 0, S2 == 0}, {phip, -0.2, 0.3}, {t, 0, 100}, 
  PlotTheme -> "Detailed", PlotPoints -> 100, 
  Epilog -> {Red, PointSize[Large], Point[p]}]
```

[image: Contourplot4]

A question, how can I insert plots here?

Comment: Use "Save Selection As" in Mathematica, save the plot as a gif or other format, use the image selector to place it in your post (sixth icon from the left).